# How do I enforce member initialization in a class under C++?

Tags: c++, string, class, visual-studio-2012, constants

I was under the assumption that a `const` member must be initialized in the class constructor.

Consider following code

```
class ABC
 {
  const string a;
  const string b;
  const string c;
  public:
  ABC( struct input in): a(in.a), b(in.b){}
};
```

I thought this would trigger a compile time error since explicit initialization for `c` is missing. However this compiles and gives empty string for `c` under VS2012. Is this correct behavior? (or special case for `string`?)

Comment: It *is* initialized. Just implicitly.

Comment: `const` means the member will not be altered once constructed; in your sample `c` is initialized using its default constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const member must be initialized when declared
```

The above holds true for only built-in and POD types.For Non-POD types, default constructor will be called which will initialize it.
`std::string` is a non-POD.

As mentioned in comments by @Dan, try changing `const string c;` to `const int c;`,the compiler will complain.

Comment: @Gaurva Sehgal must have clicked on it accidentally while accepting as answer